# Why double.infinity in container causes exception in Row, but it isn't in Cloumn (in Flutter)

Tags: flutter-layout, containers, row

I'm a new in flutter development, I have a question that I couldn't get solution or explanation for it.

Why if I put container with double.infinity, getting an exception in Row(), but it doesn't in Column() ?

the following an example of code getting exception

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return TestState();
  }
}

class TestState extends State<Test> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: const Drawer(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Text('Hello '),
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: Text(
                  'Hello',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```